# Is there a website with a list of all commercial airline incidents?

Tags: incidents, publications, flight-stat

I am looking for a website that contains a listing of all commercial airline incidents (under a sufficiently large definition of "incident"), by airline company.
I assume that incidents that happen are logged automatically somewhere, and I presume that this information may be further relayed to a public website.

---

**Here's my finding so far:**

I know of the ASRS database, https://asrs.arc.nasa.gov/search/dbol/strategies.html, but this doesn't list airline names, as far as I could see (and is also tricky to navigate).

The 3 other more usable website, that don't report just accidents, but also incidents (whatever they define as "incident"... meaning sites like http://aviation.globalincidentmap.com/ are excluded) are

https://aviation-safety.net/

http://avherald.com/

https://www.aeroinside.com/

Are these sources credible?

E.g. http://avherald.com/ states in their FAQ that they compile their report based on "own sources". https://www.aeroinside.com/ says, after some looking, that it's information is compiled from multiple other databases, but doesn't specify which. https://aviation-safety.net/ seems the most legit of these (excepting ASRS), but again, official assurances are missing.

I'm asking this, because I'd like to compile for myself some flights statistics (I'm a statistician by profession) and I'd like some site sthat are easier to navigate than ASRS (recompiling their data in a form amenable to statistics would be very time-consuming).

Comment: Please define the scope of your interest. Are you interested in US carriers, European, US & European, Global? If Global, good luck, there is no global database of incidents.

Comment: [Related meta question](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1514/62)

Comment: @CGCampbell I'm interested in European carriers flying to Asia resp. vice versa, Asian carriers flying to Europe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each jurisdiction or organization will have its own reporting system, not all will provide that information to the public. News, social media, and websites provide information but more research is required to determine which parts are accurate.

https://aviation-safety.net/

The Aviation Safety Network is probably your best bet for both completeness and accuracy. The database is fairly comprehensive, contains events as far back as 1919, and lists sources. You can browse by date, location, and aircraft type. The Wikibase allows users to add incidents, providing coverage of many more small aircraft incidents but may be less accurate.

https://avherald.com/

Avherald strives for accuracy but is far from complete. Information is not reported without reasonable verification, sources are provided when possible. The team sometimes even has access to the radar data to provide more insight. Many news outlets use this as a source. Entries go as far back as 1999, but the items are intended to provide information on accidents and an overview of the types of incidents occurring worldwide. This will make any statistical analysis hard.

https://www.aeroinside.com/

AeroInside appears to just copy from Avherald and put the entries in a fancier format with ads and make them a bit more searchable.

Comment: This is good info. As soon as I'll have 15 rep points to upvote, I'll do that.

Answer (score 4):

> under a sufficiently large definition of "incident"

Although somewhat vague, ICAO and most national regulatory agencies do have an actual definition for the term "Incident". First, however, you need to start with the term, "Accident", which can get very specific... down to the number of days someone was hospitalized, or a certain monetary damage amount, for example. Then, the definition of incident becomes, essentially, "anything that does not meet the definition of an accident, but which the safety of operations was or could have been affected." 
Source: ICAO Annex 13; US NTSB Part 830.2

> I assume that incidents that happen are logged automatically somewhere

Although I can only speak for the US, Part 830 defines what an incident is and which ones must be reported, by whom, and when.  These incidents are recorded in the online NTSB database, and can be retrieved in several formats conducive to statistical analysis (xml, csv, etc.). 
https://www.ntsb.gov/_layouts/ntsb.aviation/index.aspx

There are non-US accidents/incidents also in this database if US parts or aircraft were involved (a Boeing 737, an engine part manufactured in the US, etc.); however, these aren't as readily formatted for statistical analysis - but they do point to the foreign nation's investigative board's information.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have 15 rep to be able to upvote this, as this gives a perfect answer regarding US carriers.

Answer (score 2):

There is also [JACDEC](http://www.jacdec.de/airline-safety-ranking-2017/) (Jet Airliner Crash Data Evaluation Centre).

JADEC provide, for each airline listed, a "safety index". 
The Index is the result of a complex formular containing multiple factors such as accidents and serious incidents, revenue passenger numbers, Safety Audits, etc. 
The safety index for each airline they cover is shown on their website. Unfortunately, if you want the report that comes up with that assessment, I believe you have to pay for it.

Also, a subtle point,  JADEC is NOT a list of airlines in order of safety. Its a list of **the 60 biggest airlines** (in terms of revenue), in order of safety.

The Safety Index is calculated from a number of factors. They say:

> We believe the operational environment is a crucial factor for an airline´s safety performance.
>   One lesson of our now decade-long experience in aviation safety analysis is the following: There is a direct correlation between the safety of a airline and the competence and transparency of the controlling authorities.
>   Therefore we use for years the results of the so-called USOAP , this abbreviation stands for Universal Safety Oversight Audit Programme . In this global program, guided by all ICAO member, the whole civil aviation system is undergoing a voluntary audit. In particular it is investigated how a country is able to meet and maintain defined standards on aviation safety.
>
> Furthermore, we looked at the level of trancparency an governing authority has. We ask: Are there all relevant occurences laid on the table, or not ? Compared to earlier years, 2013 gave us some encouraging results, but many important players like China, Turkey or Mexico failed to open their accident investigations to a wider audience.

[image: Inputs for JADEC safety index.]

It's prehaps not what your loking for, because you want the raw data to make your own assessments/analysis, rather than someone elses's that includes non-statistical factors, but it seems to be quite a reputable and robust / professional assessment.