# How can I find out the reason for an aborted takeoff?

Tags: air-traffic-control, takeoff

I was listening to ATC at LAX today and heard them cancel AA 253's takeoff clearance and instruct them to abort their takeoff; it sounds like they were already rolling down the runway when it happened. The call to stop was pretty insistent.

In a lot of hours of listening, I don't remember hearing that happen before, I'm really curious why they did it. Is there any good way to find out?

Comment: You can rewind audio at [liveatc.net](http://liveatc.net). If that is what you mean.

Comment: It may get reported on the Aviation Herald, but not all do so there is no guarantee. It not there yet. http://avherald.com

Comment: There's a bunch of YouTube channels dedicated to  "live ATC" recordings. They usually combine ATC from various frequencies (e.g. approach, tower, ground) and tracking websites to create the full picture. If you're lucky your occurrence has a video.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a website with a list of all commercial airline incidents?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/46016/is-there-a-website-with-a-list-of-all-commercial-airline-incidents)

Comment: An instruction to abort takeoff by ATC to a single aircraft is almost always due traffic in its widest sense - conflicting airborne or ground traffic, runway occupancy, separation requirements and the likes. It is likely possible to find out if the traffic situation can be reconstructed (see answer on how to start below by @nabla). Had the flight crew called an abort without giving a reason, it would be much harder to know any reasons.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to listening to ATC audio recordings as suggested by previous answers or comments, you can also try to visualize the traffic situation at the time of the event using the playback feature of flight tracking websites like [FlightRadar24](http://www.flightradar24.com).

On those radar images, you can possibly see other aircraft, whether there was the danger of an imminent runway incursion, maybe the go-around of another aircraft nearby or something similar which prompted ATC to cancel the takeoff clearance. If you combine those radar playbacks with the audio recordings that you already know, you might get a pretty accurate picture of what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to find the ATC communications Archives on LiveATC.net and listen to them. They are sorted by date and time. If the reason was not mentioned by the controller on the frequency, there will be no way of knowing, unless you know someone personally from the facility or the aircrew. if it was mentioned on the frequency, you will hear it back on the website. usually a situation like the one described above would be pretty serious, for example to avoid a collision. There is a possibility that a vehicle or other aircraft crossed the runway without permission.