# Was ASRS report volume ~constant 1990 - 2005, nearly triple by 2015 then remain ~constant until 2023? If so, why is that thought to be so?

Tags: safety

[image: Screenshot from "Voluntary Data Contributions to Information Sharing August 9-10, 2016 Aviation Safety Reporting System (ASRS), Linda Connell" annotated to guide the eye and include data point from a different source in 2023.]

**above:** Screenshot from "Voluntary Data Contributions to Information Sharing August 9-10, 2016 Aviation Safety Reporting System (ASRS),  Linda Connell" annotated to guide the eye and include data point from a different source in 2023.

---

Sept. 14 2023 NASA Press Release (23-106) [UPDATE: NASA Shares UAP Independent Study Report; Names Director](https://www.nasa.gov/press-release/update-nasa-shares-uap-independent-study-report-names-director) includes

- https://go.nasa.gov/3PED0qv

which then sends readers to the 2023 [NASA Unidentified Anomalous Phenomena Independent Study Team Report](https://science.nasa.gov/science-pink/s3fs-public/atoms/files/UAP%20Independent%20Study%20Team%20-%20Final%20Report_0.pdf) which says:

> Finally, the threat to U.S. airspace safety posed by UAP is self-evident. The
> panel finds that a particularly promising avenue for deeper integration within
> a systematic, evidenced-based framework for UAP is the **Aviation Safety
> Reporting System (ASRS), which NASA administers for the FAA. This confidential and voluntary reporting system for pilots, air traffic controllers, and
> other professional aviation staff, receives approximately 100,000 reports per
> year.**

Reading further I found this 2016 [NASA ASRS Program Overview](https://www.ttsb.gov.tw/media/1281/%E8%87%AA%E9%A1%98%E5%A0%B1%E5%91%8A%E8%B3%87%E6%96%99%E5%B0%8D%E8%B3%87%E8%A8%8A%E5%88%86%E4%BA%AB%E7%9A%84%E8%B2%A2%E7%8D%BB_asrs.pdf) at (surprisingly) ttsb.gov.tw I assume there are copies of the presentation elsewhere but I couldn't find them.

Below are screenshots from slides 1 (for identification) and slide 22 "ASRS Report Volume Profile". It depicts rates of reports ramp from a few hundred to roughly 3,000 per month by 1990, stay roughly constant until about 2005, then begin what looks to me to be an at least quadratic if not exponential increase, almost trippling to 8,000 per month in 2015.

**If the 2023 NASA report block quote is accurate and I'm interpreting it correctly, the rate is currently about 8,000 per month - about the same as it was in 2015.**

**Question:** Was ASRS monthly report volume roughly constant between 1990 and 2005 almost triple between 2005 and 2015 and then again remain about constant until 2023? If so, why is that thought to be so?

Potentially helpful:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aviation_Safety_Reporting_System
- https://asrs.arc.nasa.gov/

Screenshots of slides 1 and 22 (click for full size):

[image: Screenshot of slide #1 of "Voluntary Data Contributions to Information Sharing August 9-10, 2016 Aviation Safety Reporting System (ASRS), Linda Connell"] [image: Screenshot from slide #22 of "Voluntary Data Contributions to Information Sharing August 9-10, 2016 Aviation Safety Reporting System (ASRS), Linda Connell"]

Comment: slightly related [Is there a website with a list of all commercial airline incidents?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/46016/14213) and in meta [Which website should we prefer to reference to aviation accident/incidents summaries?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1514/14213)

Comment: I didn't find a tag for "reporting" but welcome help with tagging

Comment: anecdotally, I remember some kind of grassroots marketing push for "NASA reporting" when I was in flight school, which would roughly coincide with the second surge.  I recall a lot of emphasis on it not being a mechanism for laying blame and instead being for improving safety

Comment: Since when can these reports be made online? Since when do mobile phones have good access to internet, so quick reporting was even easier? I wouldn't be surprised if there is a connection between these.

Comment: @DeltaLima Thanks for expanding your comment into a (quite thorough) answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [NASA's website](https://www.nasa.gov/ames/feature/40-Years-of-Safer-Aviation-through-Reporting) in 2016 on the 40th aniversary of the ASRS reporting:

> Since 2006, all reports are logged and processed with full anonymity
> and that de-identified data has been accessible to the public. In the
> last 10 years, the ASRS Database has had more than 189,000 queries.

Furthermore, I found the [September/October 2005 edition](https://asrs.arc.nasa.gov/docs/cb/cb_312.pdf) of CALLBACK ([ASRS Reporting Bulletin](https://asrs.arc.nasa.gov/publications/callback.html)),  which announces the introduction of email supscription to the reporting, furthermore increasing accessibility to the data.

> We will be encouraging readers to sign up for the e-mail service
> (still FREE) in lieu of the printed copy. We will continue to offer a
> print version for those who want to continue receiving paper copies.

It also announces the start of the Electronic Report Submission :

> Electronic Report Submission (ERS) is close to roll out. In addition
> to the obvious benefits for reporters, ERS will  streamline report
> handling for greater efficiency and reduce ASRS processing costs.

The [January 2007 edition](https://asrs.arc.nasa.gov/docs/cb/cb_325.pdf) of CALLBACK anounces ERS is now accessible online:

> You’ve had a brief introduction to two new ASRS  services in recent
> issues of CALLBACK – Electronic  Report Submission (ERS) and the ASRS
> Database  Online. Now we’d like to give you more information  about
> both, and explain how you can begin  accessing these new services
> through the ASRS web  site at: http://asrs.arc.nasa.gov

---

So between the end of 2005 and beginning of 2007 the following changed:

1. reports were now logged and processed with full anonymity
2. reports could be submitted electronically
3. de-identified data has been accessible to the public
4. subscription to the ASRS bulletin could be done via email

Full anonymity would lower the barrier that people feel to make the report, electronic submission would make it even easier, whilst making de-identified data accessible to the public and email subscription to the ASRS bulletin would increase the general awareness of ASRS existence.

This started to drive the growth of the ASRS reporting rate, further accelerated by the improvement in mobile internet accessibility lowering the reporting barrier even more.

---

I found a presentation from [July 2023](https://asrs.arc.nasa.gov/docs/ASRS_ProgramBriefing.pdf), showing the full graph of report intake from January 1981 until December 2022 on page 13.

[image: Chart of ASRS report intake over the years 1981-2022]

This shows that after 2015, the growth of reporting rate reduced, with the peak of reporting rate in 2019 at about 9000 reports per month.

It seems that by 2015, ASRS was so widely known that the awareness is saturating and the growth stagnates.

During COVID the rate fell by about 35%, and came back to 2015 levels of approximately 8000 reports per month in December 2022. Since air traffic levels were still below the 2019 level, this is not unexpected.